# How to insert an image in proper alignment in bootstrap navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The navigation bar of my webpage looks like below where {{heading}} is getting evaluated as "Introduction to metrics management" when it is rendered. The html using bootstrap looks like below :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ heading }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bs-iso">
    <nav class="bs-iso navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="bs-iso container-fluid">
            <div class="bs-iso navbar-header">
                <a  class="bs-iso navbar-brand" href="/">{{heading}}</a><a id="foo" class="bs-iso navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <div class=" bs-iso navbar-text navbar-right" style="margin-right:14px;">
                Sign In !
            </div>
```

Now, I want to insert an image just before the heading in the body. I am fetching that image from a certain path and trying to render that. However the image and the heading is not coming inline and with proper alignment. Is there any special bootstrap class or css setting that I need to use to get that properly ? 
Below is the html after inserting that image tag :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ heading }}</title>
    {{> css }}
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bs-iso">
    <nav class="bs-iso navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="bs-iso container-fluid">
            <div class="bs-iso navbar-header">
                <a  class="bs-iso navbar-brand" style='padding:0 !important' href="/">
                <table><tr><td><img class='img-responsive2' src = 'image/foo.jpg'></td></tr></table>

                {{heading}}</a><a id="foo" class="bs-iso navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <div class=" bs-iso navbar-text navbar-right" style="margin-right:14px;">
                Sign In !
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can u try this

**HTML tag**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="images/Logos.png" alt="company" class="img-resonsive"></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-brand {
        height: auto !important;
        padding: 10px 5px !important;
    }
```

But my picture me use size 141x147

Comment: thanks first of all for replying. It is partially working for me. The image is coming with proper alignment however the text (i.e heading) has shifted down a bit.

Comment: With a little tweak in my html, your solution is working. Thanks.